# SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

Does anyone know why I get this error when I try to load multiple dataframes using different threads in Scala.

> SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0

Here is my code:

```
val dataFrame = connector.createDataFrame(query)
dataFrame.printSchema()
println(dataFrame.count())

val dataFrame2 = connector.createDataFrame(query2)
dataFrame2.printSchema()
println(dataFrame2.count())
```

The problem is when I try to perform any operation, and it is not for lack of memory because each Dataframe only has 100 rows.

Comment: What was the error you got? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) just an FYI

Comment: The error I got is -> SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0"